# It seems `setVelocityX` doesn't agree with the keystrokes. Am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm learning Phaser3 following a [tutorial](https://gamedevacademy.org/how-to-create-a-turn-based-rpg-game-in-phaser-3-part-1/).

Here is the code I ported from the tutorial.

```js
class BootScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({
      key: 'BootScene'
    });
  }

  preload() {
        // map tiles
        this.load.image('tiles', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/liyi93319/phaser3_rpg/main/part1/assets/map/spritesheet.png');
        
        // map in json format
        this.load.tilemapTiledJSON('map', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/liyi93319/phaser3_rpg/main/part1/assets/map/map.json');
        
        // our two characters
        this.load.spritesheet('player', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/liyi93319/phaser3_rpg/main/part1/assets/RPG_assets.png', { frameWidth: 16, frameHeight: 16 });
  }

  create() {
    this.scene.start('WorldScene');
  }
}

class WorldScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({
      key: 'WorldScene'
    });
  }

  create() {
    // create your world here
    var map = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'map' });
    // creates a tileset image
    var tiles = map.addTilesetImage('spritesheet', 'tiles');
    var grass = map.createLayer('Grass', tiles, 0, 0);
    var obstacles = map.createLayer('Obstacles', tiles, 0, 0);
    obstacles.setCollisionByExclusion([-1]);
    this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(25, 25, 'player', 6);
    this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
  }

  update(time, delta) {
    this.player.body.setVelocity(0);
    // Horizontal movement
    if (this.cursors.left.isDown) {
      this.player.body.setVelocityX(-80);
    }
    else if (this.cursors.right.isDown) {
      this.player.body.setVelocityX(80);
    }
    // Vertical movement
    if (this.cursors.up.isDown) {
      this.player.body.setVelocityY(-80);
    }
    else if (this.cursors.down.isDown) {
      this.player.body.setVelocityY(80);
    }
  }
}

var bootScene = new BootScene();
var worldScene = new WorldScene();

var config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  parent: 'content',
  width: 320,
  height: 240,
  zoom: 2,
  pixelArt: true,
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
    arcade: {
      gravity: { y: 0 }
    }
  },
  scene: [
    BootScene,
    WorldScene
  ]
};
var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

I'm confused about the `setVelocityX` method. Per the [doc](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#setVelocityX), the method sets

> the velocity, in pixels per second.

To examine this, I moved the player to the left of a tree

[image]

and tapped right arrow key quickly. It took about 4 taps to move the player from the left to the right.

[image]

I guess the tree I used as the reference could count as a tile, which has width of 16, per [map.json](https://github.com/liyi93319/phaser3_rpg/blob/main/part1/assets/map/map.json). So, one keystroke represents about 3~4 pixels whereas the code

```
this.player.body.setVelocityX(-80);
```

set the velocity 80 pixels per second.

It seems `setVelocityX` doesn't agree with the keystrokes. Am I missing something?

PS: I did hold the key for 1 full second but the player didn't move 80 pixels either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you only tap, it **doesn't** move for a full second. just how long the key is hold down (can be some milliseconds).

And it also depends on the update rate of the `update` function, it is not always constant. (you can see that through the parameter `delta` passed to the update function, `update(time, delta)`) Here the [link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Time.Clock.html#update__anchor)

> If you want to test it, just hold the key for 1 second. btw.: `drag` and `acceleration` can come also into play, if set.

**Edited so that is logs the position after 1 second:**
*the results will vary depending on the computer, but for me it is about 80px*

```js
class BootScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({
      key: 'BootScene'
    });
  }

  preload() {
        // map tiles
        this.load.image('tiles', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/liyi93319/phaser3_rpg/main/part1/assets/map/spritesheet.png');
        
        // map in json format
        this.load.tilemapTiledJSON('map', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/liyi93319/phaser3_rpg/main/part1/assets/map/map.json');
        
        // our two characters
        this.load.spritesheet('player', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/liyi93319/phaser3_rpg/main/part1/assets/RPG_assets.png', { frameWidth: 16, frameHeight: 16 });
  }

  create() {
    this.scene.start('WorldScene');
  }
}

class WorldScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({
      key: 'WorldScene'
    });
  }

  create() {
    // create your world here
    var map = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'map' });
    // creates a tileset image
    var tiles = map.addTilesetImage('spritesheet', 'tiles');
    var grass = map.createLayer('Grass', tiles, 0, 0);
    var obstacles = map.createLayer('Obstacles', tiles, 0, 0);
    obstacles.setCollisionByExclusion([-1]);
    this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(25, 25, 'player', 6);
    this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
  }

  update(time, delta) {
    this.player.body.setVelocity(0);
   
    // Horizontal movement
    if (this.cursors.left.isDown) {
      this.player.body.setVelocityX(-80);
      if(!this._press){
       this.start = (new Date()).getTime();
       this.startX = this.player.body.x; 
        this._press = true;
       setTimeout(()=>{
        console.info(`Started at x-Position: ${this.startX} -> Ended at x-Position: ${this.player.body.x} = distance: ${ Math.abs(this.player.body.x - this.startX) }`);
       }, 1000)
       }
    }
    else if (this.cursors.right.isDown) {
      this.player.body.setVelocityX(80);
    }
    // Vertical movement
    if (this.cursors.up.isDown) {
      this.player.body.setVelocityY(-80);
    }
    else if (this.cursors.down.isDown) {
      this.player.body.setVelocityY(80);
    }
  }
}

var bootScene = new BootScene();
var worldScene = new WorldScene();

var config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  parent: 'content',
  width: 320,
  height: 240,
  zoom: 2,
  pixelArt: true,
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
    arcade: {
      gravity: { y: 0 }
    }
  },
  scene: [
    BootScene,
    WorldScene
  ]
};
var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

> My result was: `Started at x-Position: 135.66666666666652 -> Ended at x-Position: 55.66666666666669 = distance: 79.99999999999983`

Comment: Thanks, I did hold the key for 1 full second but the player didn't move 80 pixels either.

Comment: @yaojp  I updated my answer to showcase, that it should work. But the result will vary, depending on the power of the PC you are using. You can see it, if you press and hold `left` key, after 1 second the start x position and the final x-Position will be displayed in the `console`.